# Tensorflow:assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound]

Tags: tensorflow, label

Getting a 'Label out of bound' error while running the testing script. Error is thrown in the confusion_matrix function when the annotation values are compared with the number of classes. In my case annotation value is an image(560x560) and number_of_classes = 2.

```
[check_ops.assert_less(labels, num_classes_int64, message='`labels` out of bound')], labels
```

The above condition is always going to fail, as the annotation data is bigger than number of classes.

First, There is a good chance that I am misunderstanding the code, but I can not make any sense of it.

Second, If this is a valid check, then how can I modify my code or data to avoid this error.

```py
def confusion_matrix(labels, predictions, num_classes=None, dtype=dtypes.int32,
                     name=None, weights=None):
 with ops.name_scope(name, 'confusion_matrix',
                      (predictions, labels, num_classes, weights)) as name:
    labels, predictions = remove_squeezable_dimensions(
        ops.convert_to_tensor(labels, name='labels'),
        ops.convert_to_tensor(
            predictions, name='predictions'))
    predictions = math_ops.cast(predictions, dtypes.int64)
    labels = math_ops.cast(labels, dtypes.int64)

    # Sanity checks - underflow or overflow can cause memory corruption.
    labels = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(
        [check_ops.assert_non_negative(
            labels, message='`labels` contains negative values')],
        labels)
    predictions = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(
        [check_ops.assert_non_negative(
            predictions, message='`predictions` contains negative values')],
        predictions)
    print(num_classes)
    if num_classes is None:
      num_classes = math_ops.maximum(math_ops.reduce_max(predictions),
                                     math_ops.reduce_max(labels)) + 1
      #$

    else:
      num_classes_int64 = math_ops.cast(num_classes, dtypes.int64)
      ---->>labels = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(
          [check_ops.assert_less(
              labels, num_classes_int64, message='`labels` out of bound')],
          labels)<<----
      predictions = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(
          [check_ops.assert_less(
              predictions, num_classes_int64,
              message='`predictions` out of bound')],
          predictions)

    if weights is not None:
      predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(weights.get_shape())
      weights = math_ops.cast(weights, dtype)

    shape = array_ops.stack([num_classes, num_classes])
    indices = array_ops.transpose(array_ops.stack([labels, predictions]))
    values = (array_ops.ones_like(predictions, dtype)
              if weights is None else weights)
    cm_sparse = sparse_tensor.SparseTensor(
        indices=indices, values=values, dense_shape=math_ops.to_int64(shape))
    zero_matrix = array_ops.zeros(math_ops.to_int32(shape), dtype)

    return sparse_ops.sparse_add(zero_matrix, cm_sparse)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:x (mean_iou/confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [0 0 0...] [y (mean_iou/ToInt64_2:0) = ] [21]
     [[Node: mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_3, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/supriya.godge/PycharmProjects/tf-image-segmentation/tf_image_segmentation/recipes/pascal_voc/DeepLab/output/resnet_v1_101_8s_test_airplan.py", line 81, in <module>
    image_np, annotation_np, pred_np, tmp = sess.run([image, annotation, pred, update_op])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:x (mean_iou/confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [0 0 0...] [y (mean_iou/ToInt64_2:0) = ] [21]
     [[Node: mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_3, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2)]]

Caused by op 'mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert', defined at:
  File "C:/Users/supriya.godge/PycharmProjects/tf-image-segmentation/tf_image_segmentation/recipes/pascal_voc/DeepLab/output/resnet_v1_101_8s_test_airplan.py", line 64, in <module>
    weights=weights)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\metrics\python\ops\metric_ops.py", line 2245, in streaming_mean_iou
    updates_collections=updates_collections, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\metrics_impl.py", line 917, in mean_iou
    num_classes, weights)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\metrics_impl.py", line 285, in _streaming_confusion_matrix
    labels, predictions, num_classes, weights=weights, dtype=cm_dtype)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\confusion_matrix.py", line 178, in confusion_matrix
    labels, num_classes_int64, message='`labels` out of bound')],
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\check_ops.py", line 401, in assert_less
    return control_flow_ops.Assert(condition, data, summarize=summarize)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_should_use.py", line 175, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 131, in Assert
    condition, no_op, true_assert, name="AssertGuard")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 296, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1828, in cond
    orig_res_f, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(false_fn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1694, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 129, in true_assert
    condition, data, summarize, name="Assert")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 35, in _assert
    summarize=summarize, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:x (mean_iou/confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [0 0 0...] [y (mean_iou/ToInt64_2:0) = ] [21]
     [[Node: mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_3, mean_iou/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2)]]
```

I am really lost here so any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here.

The 'labels' array, `Y_true`, had values `0, 255`. I used:

```
Y_true = Y_true/255
```

to squash `Y_true` to `0, 1`.

That removed the error.

Answer (score 3):

In the Annotation file, the labels were 0,1,2,255. The range of label was given 3. So when 255 was detected in the annotation file above error was thrown. After I removed all 255 values the code worked without any error.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has encountered this issue and not been able to resolve by rescaling or adjusting channels, I found that the MeanIOU metric also causes this issue. Getting rid of it and training with only loss as a metric or defining another one worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I was accidentally providing `num_classes=1` for a binary task, so increased the number by 1 and the training began to work.

Answer (score 1):

under tensorflow 1.15.2, tensorflow/models/research/deeplab is basically quite ok.

error message like:

Invalid argument: assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (mean_iou/confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ]

likely due not considering background as 1 class. e.g. deeplab/datasets/data_generator.py

```
# Number of semantic classes, including the
# background class (if exists). For example, there
# are 20 foreground classes + 1 background class in
# the PASCAL VOC 2012 dataset. Thus, we set
# num_classes=21.
```

Answer (score 1):

Same error here.
My error was due to I was using the checkpoint of cityscapes. `Cityscapes` have more labels than my data, so when I change the label number from 2 to 19 (which is the label number of cityscapes), `eval.py` runs perfectly. However, there might be some conflicts between `cityscapes` labels and own data labels. That needs further modification.